# Pandas dataframe to json without index

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to take a dataframe and transform it into a partcular json format.

Here's my dataframe example:

```
DataFrame name: Stops
id    location
0     [50, 50]
1     [60, 60]
2     [70, 70]
3     [80, 80]
```

Here's the json format I'd like to transform into:

```
"stops":
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "location": [50, 50]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "location": [60, 60]
},
... (and so on)
]
```

Notice it's a list of dicts.  I have it nearly there with the following code:

`df.reset_index().to_json(orient='index)`

However, that line also includes the index like this:

```
"stops":
{
"0":
    {
        "id": 0,
        "location": [50, 50]
    },
"1":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": [60, 60]
    },
... (and so on)
}
```

Notice this is a dict of dicts and also includes the index twice (in the first dict and as the "id" in the second dict!  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the behavior changed?  I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use [`orient='records'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
print df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')

[
     {"id":0,"location":"[50, 50]"},
     {"id":1,"location":"[60, 60]"},
     {"id":2,"location":"[70, 70]"},
     {"id":3,"location":"[80, 80]"}
]
```

Comment: That is so simple.  I love pandas ... and you!  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want index at all, just remove "reset_index()" part.

Comment: Found this in accident.

Answer (score 5):

Since 2017 there is an `index=False` option. Use it with `orient='split'` or `orient='table'`.  Credit to this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438648/1056563

```
    dfj = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='table',index=False))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Python **dict** (the JSON-object equivalent in python) not a JSON string:

```py
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way as well.

```
df_dict=df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='index')
df_vals=list(df_dict.values())
```