# Convert numpy.nd array to json

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy

I've a data frame genre_rail in which one column contains `numpy.ndarray`. The dataframe looks like as given below[image: datframe]

The array in it looks like this :

```
['SINGTEL_movie_22906' 'SINGTEL_movie_22943' 'SINGTEL_movie_24404'
 'SINGTEL_movie_22924' 'SINGTEL_movie_22937' 'SINGTEL_movie_22900'
 'SINGTEL_movie_24416' 'SINGTEL_movie_24422']
```

I tried with the  following code

```
import json
json_content = json.dumps({'mydata': [genre_rail.iloc[i]['content_id'] for i in range(len(genre_rail))] })
```

But got an error

> TypeError: array is not JSON serializable

I need output as

```
{"Rail2_contend_id":
["SINGTEL_movie_22894","SINGTEL_movie_22898",
"SINGTEL_movie_22896","SINGTEL_movie_24609","SINGTEL_movie_2455",
"SINGTEL_movie_24550","SINGTEL_movie_24548","SINGTEL_movie_24546"]}
```

Comment: Since you mention dataframe, there are also [Pandas dataframe to json without index](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28590663/3005167) and [Convert pandas dataframe to json format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39257147/3005167)

Comment: The question is also outdated. By now pandas has `df.to_json(PATH_HERE, orient='records')`. Check out the function documentation regarding `orient` for various formats of the json structure.

Answer (score 21):

How about you convert the array to json using the `.tolist` method.
Then you can write it to json like :

```
np_array_to_list = np_array.tolist()
json_file = "file.json" 
json.dump(b, codecs.open(json_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8'), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it seems that the program stucked at `tolist()`.

Comment: @yurenzhong `tolist()` has proceeded with very long computation time to me

Answer (score 8):

Load all the data in dictionary, then dump it to json. Below code might help you

```
import json

#Data
d = ['SINGTEL_movie_22906', 'SINGTEL_movie_22943', 'SINGTEL_movie_24404'
 'SINGTEL_movie_22924', 'SINGTEL_movie_22937', 'SINGTEL_movie_22900'
 'SINGTEL_movie_24416', 'SINGTEL_movie_24422']

#Create dict
dic = {}
dic['Rail2_contend_id'] = d

print dic

#Dump data dict to jason
j = json.dumps(dic)
```

Output

{'Rail2_contend_id': ['SINGTEL_movie_22906', 'SINGTEL_movie_22943', 'SINGTEL_movie_24404SINGTEL_movie_22924', 'SINGTEL_movie_22937', 'SINGTEL_movie_22900SINGTEL_movie_24416', 'SINGTEL_movie_24422']}