# Remove index from dataframe before converting to json with split orientation

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am outputting a pandas dataframe to a json object using the following:

```
df_as_json = df.to_json(orient='split')
```

In the json object superfluous indexes are stored. I do no want to include these.

To remove them I tried

```
df_no_index = df.to_json(orient='records')
df_as_json = df_no_index.to_json(orient='split')
```

However I get a

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

Is there a fast way to reorganize the dataframe so that is does not contain a separate index column during or prior to the .to_json(orient='split') call?

Comment: have you tried orient='records'

Comment: This doesn't work because `to_json` doesn't return a pandas data frame and therefore the next call of `to_json` cannot work.

Comment: @StevenG yes, this sends the column names as keys which increases file size by 30% (which I dont want to do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- import json module
- Convert to `json` with `to_json(orient='split')`
- Use the `json` module to load that string to a dictionary
- Delete the `index` key with `del json_dict['index']`
- Convert the dictionary back to `json` with `json.dump` or `json.dumps`

---

***Demo***

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'])

json_dict = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='split'))
del json_dict['index']
json.dumps(json_dict)

'{"columns": ["a", "b"], "data": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}'
```

Comment: Alternatively, go via a dictionary to start with, i.e:  `data = df.to_dict(orient='split')` followed by `del data['index']`...

Answer (score 5):

[Since two years back](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/18591) `pandas` ([>= v0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/whatsnew.html#v0-23-0)) offers an `index` argument (only valid for `orient='split'` and `orient='table'`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'])
df.to_json(orient='split', index=True)
# '{"columns":["a","b"],"index":["x","y"],"data":[[1,2],[3,4]]}'
df.to_json(orient='split', index=False)
# '{"columns":["a","b"],"data":[[1,2],[3,4]]}'
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html