# How to include Dataframe's name on to_json (Pandas)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Using the dataset of this question ([Pandas dataframe to json without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590663/pandas-dataframe-to-json-without-index)), how can I add the name of the dataframe?

`to_json()` is returning me this:

```
[
 {"id":0,"location":"[50, 50]"},
 {"id":1,"location":"[60, 60]"},
 {"id":2,"location":"[70, 70]"},
 {"id":3,"location":"[80, 80]"}
]
```

but I want JSON like this:

```
{
"stops":
[
 {"id":0,"location":"[50, 50]"},
 {"id":1,"location":"[60, 60]"},
 {"id":2,"location":"[70, 70]"},
 {"id":3,"location":"[80, 80]"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [77]: d = {'stops':df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')}

In [78]: js = json.dumps(d, indent=2)

In [79]: print(js)
{
  "stops": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "location": "[50, 50]"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "location": "[60, 60]"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "location": "[70, 70]"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "location": "[80, 80]"
    }
  ]
}
```